# Overwrite an assembly from a NuGet package with my forked version?

Tags: c#, .net, assembly-binding-redirect

I'm using a 3rd party's NuGet package that includes a .net assembly that contains a bug. I've forked this project and fixed the bug. In my own projects I can reference the assembly from the forked version. Unfortunately multiple other NuGet packages indirectly depend on the NuGet package with the bug. Is there some policy, or mechanism similar to assembly redirects that allows me to always load my version of the assembly?

Ideally I could do something like this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="FooBar"  
                      publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"  
                      culture="en-us" />  

    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0" newVersion="C:/files/FooBarFixed.dll" />  
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I suppose creating a pull-request on the buggy library is not an option?

Comment: Take a look on `<codeBase>` element [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/codebase-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: You can increase a version of forked version and add a reference directly to projects, where version with bug is used as transitive dependency. The higher version should have a precedence

Comment: @PMF it is, but they release new versions roughly once a year :)

Not sure if I can use <codebase> here. But I'll try Pavel's suggestion!